# How can I select rows which foreign key relation elements are ONLY past in time or don't exist at all

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables:

1. event_serie
2. event

Every '**event**' has a relation to '**event_serie**' by **event_serie_id** foreign key and **date_time** column which is obviously time when event starts (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format).

Now the funny and very difficult part for me - how can I select 'event_serie' which have events from the past **ONLY** or **NO** events at all? In other words I need to find 'event_serie' which have no today & future or 0 events.

I will appreciate both mysql and doctrine2 examples(if only it's possible to do with DQL actually).

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_other_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.date >= NOW()
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

?

Comment: `My_table` in your example don't have `date` column.

Comment: Excellent Strawberry! Seems so simple now ;) I've just changed CURDATE() to NOW() to match also today's past events. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.latestDate
FROM
        event a
        LEFT JOIN event_serie b
            ON a.event_serie_id = b.event_serie_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  event_serie_id, MAX(date_time) latestDate
            FROM    event_serie
            GROUP   BY event_serie_id
        ) c ON a.event_serie_id = c.event_serie_id
WHERE   b.event_serie_id IS NULL OR
        b.date_time < c.latestDate
```